# I am using JSF 2.2 and returning null or "" string from bean method but page is rendering blank

Tags: jsf-2, jsf-2.2

In my application we are using JSF 2.2 and in one of the functionality we need to display the same page. For that we are returning null or "" string from the method. But page is rendering blank.

Note: In JSf 1.2 this is working.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: IDE RAD 9.0, Websphere 8.5, JSF 2.2, Java 1.7. I am returning the string from the action method which is configured in the faces-config.xml (navigation case to same page), in this action method I am also adding FacesMessage to FacesContext addMessage method.
Issue: Page is rendering blank, in the console I am not seeing any error.

Comment: You need to provide your JSF configuration (web.xml) and the code used in the view file and the managed bean. I guess it is difficult because it seems you're migrating from a legacy project, but as the first comment says, you should try to provide an example we can run. If you can't with your current code, try to setup a project from scratch and port the configuration until you get the same issue.